# MS Access trimming trailing spaces from text field on import

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am importing some data from a text file into Access.

One of the fields is a text field which has a number of spaces at the end.

Access trims these spaces off when I import the file. Is it possible to stop this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is no text qualifier there is no real way to do this in Access.

You may import this into Excel where it will preserve the trailing spaces, write a formula to append a character to the end, then save and import this file into Access and remove the trailing character.

If there is a text qualifier you can specify no text qualifier on import in Access, then strip it off later.

Comment: I was able to get delimiters in my CSV so I did what you suggested, imported the quotes into the field then stripped them out. Thanks.